# Calling JCrop in GWT JSNI

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni, jcrop

I'm trying to make a JSNI call equivalent to this JavaScript snippet:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#target').Jcrop();
});
```

I believe i have correctly imported the libraries but i can't seem to get the syntax right on calling this function from JSNI. When using the following method:

```java
public static final native void initializeJCrop() /*-{
    $wnd.jQuery(function($) {
        $('#target').Jcrop();
    });
}-*/;
```

The following exception is thrown:

> Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException:
>   (TypeError): $("#target").Jcrop is not a function

How i can fix this?

Comment: If you open your developer tools (Firebug, Firefox console, Chrome Developer Tools, etc.) and type `$('#target').Jcrop()` in the console, does it work? If it doesn't, then it's not an issue with JSNI.

Comment: did you remember to update your `.gwt.xml` to reference the `Jcrop` sources?

Answer (score -2):

The syntax for calling external functions using JSNI is a bit different than simple JavaScript.

You have to provide the complete package/class reference along with the types/classes of parameters of the function being called (Since yours does not have any parameters, you needn't worry)
Try changing the call to include the *package* and *class* where JCrop is defined. 
Lets say the location of class defining JCrop is "api.jcrop"

Then your call must be

```
    @api.jcrop::JCrop()()
```

instead of JCrop()

Of course the package names are hypothetical and you must check the correct location of the class containing the definition.

The sign @ is necessary. jcrop is the class containing the definition and JCrop() is the function itself.

The first parantheses after JCrop denotes the type of parameter for the function while the second provides the values of passed parameters. As I said, both are empty in your case.

If you're interested, you can read more about parameters [here](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/ajax/GWT-JSNI.pdf)

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: I'm fairly certain that isn't the cause, since Jcrop isn't a Java library, so isn't going to have a package, or classes. Jcrop appears to be a JQuery library, available at https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop

Comment: That is probably true. Have a look at [this page](http://varuntayur.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/howto-jquery-gwt-integration/) and see if it helps.